# Spring config, need to reference classes in imported project

Tags: spring

I am developing a system which has a batch and a web portion, and since the database-related stuff will be shared between the two, I have set up a separate "Shared" project for the database stuff.  I am doing the Web portion first, and when I try to create the beans in xml (referencing the classes in the Shared project), I get ClassNotFound exception.  Does anyone know how I can do this?  I don't want to create all those classes, and all those iBatis files, in both my Batch and Web application.  I hope I can keep them in Shared.

Thanks!
--Tom

Comment: You should have your Shared project built and it's jar available on the classpath of your web project. That is all.

Comment: Nikem, thanks for the reply.  This is a Maven system, and I'd think Maven would resolve this.  I do have the "Shared" project as a dependency in my Web project's pom.xml, and I get the ClassNotFound errors.  I then explicitly added the Shared project's jar file, in Eclipse's Properties box / Libraries tab.  I still get the ClassNotFound.

Comment: The "shared" jar IS in the created war file of the Web project, at WEB-INF/lib, just as I'd expect.  But I still get the ClassNotFound errors on startup.

Comment: Then show us your xml config.